# problema con una consulta preparada en php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera pedir su ayuda con el código de un formulario de registro el cual estoy intentando cambiar para que use consultas preparadas:

```
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE correo='$correo'");
$fila2=mysqli_fetch_array($registros2); 

mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO codigos (codigo,fecha_antigua,id_cliente) VALUES ('$codigo','$fecha','$fila2[id_cliente]')");
```

no se exactamente como hacer una consulta preparada de este query debido al $fila2[id_cliente]. 
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: has un `var_dump($fila2);` y posiblemente sabras que hacer despues, ahi te arrojara las llaves que tienen los array

Comment: **Ninguna** de tus dos consultas aplica bien el criterio de consultas preparadas. La primera sería así: `SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE correo=?` y la segunda sería: `INSERT INTO codigos (codigo,fecha_antigua,id_cliente) VALUES (?,?,?)`. El **fundamento** de las consultas preparadas es **no pasar el dato junto con la instrucción SQL, para evitar de ese modo la inyección de código y también para poder reutilizar la consulta si fuera necesario**. Por eso ves que hay marcadores. Y luego debes usar `bind_param` para pasar los datos. Recomendaría que revises la documentación.

Comment: Buen dia. Creo que no me explique bien,  yo si se como hacer una consulta preparada, lo que no sabia era como hacer para recibir el valor de $fila2[id_cliente] en una consulta preparada, de todas formas ya lo solucione. Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Te saludo y te comento lo siguiente; primero tu consulta de `SELECT()` debería quedar así

```
$registros2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_cliente FROM cliente WHERE correo = ? ");
$registros2->bind_param("s", $correo);
$registros2->execute();
```

EXPLICACIÓN

> La variable `$registros2` se iguala al objeto de conexión `$conexion`y
>   este a su vez accede al método `prepare`; como esta consulta funciona
>   con valores externos y queremos usar sentencias preparadas; usamos
>   marcadores de posición `?` para identificar la ubicación de la
>   variable `$correo`
>
> Con el método `bind_param()` indicamos el parámetro dinámico que se va
>   a recibir es decir la variable $correo; a su vez dentro de comillas
>   indicamos el tipo de dato que estamos mandando; donde `s` es para
>   `strings` e `i` para `integers`
>
> Finalmente con la variable $registro2 accedemos al método `execute()`
>   que a su vez ejecutará la sentencia anterior

**PARA TU SEGUNDA SENTENCIA, DEBERÍA QUEDAR**

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO codigos(codigo, fecha_antigua, id_cliente) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $codigo);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fecha_antigua);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id_cliente);
$stmt->execute();
```

Solo debes verificar que los tipos de datos en `bind_param()` correspodan pues los coloco a como interpreto que serían

```
s => string
i => integer
d => double
b => blob
```

> La necesidad de usar los marcadores de posición, que en mysqli son el
>   `?` y en PDO son los `:` mas un nombre descriptivo, es para indicar a
>   donde ocurrirá la interpolación de ese marcador por el valor dinámico
>   que esta llegando de alguna variable

Answer (score 0):

Ninguna de tus dos consultas cumple con el criterio de **consultas preparadas**.

En resumen, una consulta preparada comprende varias etapas:

1. Escribir la consulta a preparar, la cual no debe llevar datos en sí misma, sino marcadores para cada dato.
2. Mandar a preparar la consulta con `prepare`
3. Pasar los valores aparte mediante el método `bind_param`
4. Ejecutar la consulta con `execute`
5. Eventualmente hacer un `bind_value` para obtener los valores (en caso de consultas `SELECT`). O usar otro método de almacenamiento de resultados.

Para cumplir con dichos criterios, puedes escribir tu código así:

```
$sqlCliente="SELECT id_cliente FROM clientes WHERE correo=?";
$stmtCliente=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sqlCliente);
/*
    La letra "s"  indica que el tipo de dato es varchar (string)
    si fuese un entero se pondría una "i"
    si fuese un doble una "d"  y si fuese del tipo blob una "b"
*/
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtCliente,"s",$correo);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtCliente);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmtCliente, $idCliente);

$sqlCodigo="INSERT INTO codigos (codigo,fecha_antigua,id_cliente) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmtCodigo=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sqlCodigo);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtCodigo,"ssi",$codigo,$fecha,$idCliente);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtCodigo);
```

He usado nombres de variables más descriptivos. Y he respetado el estilo procedural que muestras en tu código, aunque el estilo orientado a objetos es más moderno y convendría aprenderlo.

Si hay alguna duda puedes decirlo en comentarios.

Espero te sea de utilidad.